# Conditional fetch data after login codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, fetch

I've made a login system which validates if the user is an ADMIN or a simple user.

My tables are "cursadas","usuarios" and "materias"

> "cursadas" includes:**(id, user_id[is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table "usuarios"], subject_id[is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table "materias"], grade, date)**
>
> "usuarios" includes:**(id,username,name,lastname,password,type,status,date)**
>
> "materias" includes:**(id, career_id, name, description, hours)**

This is my table "usuarios":

[image]

And i've done another program that fetch data from tables "usuarios" and "materias" AND put that information into the table "cursadas".

This is my final table "cursadas"(with data from tables "materias" and "usuarios")

[image]

NOW, I wanna make something new. Working with the login system and my table "cursadas". If a simple user (not ADMIN-i mean ("type" = 1  AND "status" = 1)) that username must be able to see their information stored in the table "cursadas"

**If the username & password written in the login system correspond ONLY to a simple user *("type" = 1  AND "status" = 1)* a table with the information of the username written in the login system must be shown**

TAKE A LOOK, i need something like this:

[image]

**Note: in this case there is only 1 username, but i will add more users with the condition ("type" = 1  AND "status" = 1) and everytime i log in with the different usernames and passwords a table with the information of the different usernames MUST BE SHOWN**

***Here is my login code:***

My view file ("login_form"):

```
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <hr>
            <form action="<?php echo base_url('login/do_login')?>" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cari">USERNAME</label>
                    <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control">

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cari">PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" class="form-control">

                </div>

                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" name="login">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">

            </form>
                </div>



        </body>
</html>
```

My controller file ("login"):

```
    <?php

        Class Login extends CI_Controller{


        public function index(){
 

           $this->load->view('login_form');


        }

 public function do_login()
        {
         // load the form_validation library
         $this->load->library('form_validation');

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('usuario', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|alpha_numeric');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('contrasena', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');

           // if there is errors
         if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { 
            // this will load your form with the errors
        
               $this->load->view('Login_main'); 

         } else {
           // if no errors we will hit the database
            $user=$this->input->post('usuario', true);
            $pass=$this->input->post('contrasena', true);
            $cek = $this->m_login->proceso_login($user,$pass);
            $hasil=count($cek);

            if($hasil > 0){

                $pelogin =$this->db->get_where('usuarios',array('username' => $user, 'password' => $pass))->row();

                if($pelogin ->type == 0){
                    redirect('login/admin');
                }

                else{
                    redirect('login/usuario');
                }
            }
            redirect('login/index');
        }
    }
```

My model file ("m_login"):

```
    <?php

        class M_login extends CI_Model{

            public function proceso_login($user,$pass){

                $this->db->where('username', $user);
                $this->db->where('password', $pass);
                return $this->db->get('usuarios')->row();

            }


}
?>
```

***AND my "cursadas" file:***

My view file ("home"):

```
    <html>
 
    <head>
 
 
 
    </head>
 
<body>
 
    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
 
        <h2 align="center">TABLE:Study</h2>
 
        <input id="busqueda_tabla" type="text">
            <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </thead>
 
<tbody>
    <?php
 
    if (count($records) > 0 && $records != false) {
        foreach($records as $record) {
 
            echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$record['ID']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['User']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['name']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['grade']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['date']."</td>
                      <td align='center'>
 
                        <a href='".site_url('Home/editar')."/$record[ID]'> 
                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDITAR</button></a> |
                        <a href='".site_url('Home/borrar')."/$record[ID]'> 
                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>

                  </tr>";
        }
 
       }
    ?>
 
</tbody>
 
    </table>
 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

My controller file ("Home"):

```
    <?php
 
    class Home extends CI_Controller{
 
         public function __construct(){
             parent::__construct();
             $this->load->model("Crudmodel");
 
        }
 
 
public function index(){
 
    # get all data in Study table
 
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT a.id ID,b.username User, c.name, a.grade, a.date FROM cursadas a JOIN usuarios b ON a.user_id=b.id JOIN materias c ON c.id=a.subject_id');
 
    $result = $query->result_array();
 
    $data['records'] = $result;
 
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
 
}
```

Dont know what to do now :/

Comment: Do not store plain text passwords

Comment: you have a lot of unnecessary details in the question which were not needed at all. Besides restructuring your project for security, you only need a query to fetch desired records from the table

Comment: and please keep state of the user in session.

Comment: What should i do then pal?, i am a little dizzy:/

Comment: @MalikMudassar really do not know what to do :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your desired ERD

[image]

You case is a simple example of Role Based User Login / Environments. Now if you can look at this [Boiler-Plates-Codeigniter-3.x-Login](https://github.com/malikmudassar/Boiler-Plates-Codeigniter-3.x-Login). You will have a solid understanding about code and structuring for creating a good role based login and how to keep user details in session in Codeigniter.

Once you are successfully logged in you need to create model function, call it in your controller by which you are rendering your current user dashboard / view and then send that data to your view which you got from your model function

E.g. In your controller. Make a function for home

```
public function home()
{
    $data['record']=$this->M_login->getDetails();
    $this->load->view('home',$data);
}
```

In your Model Make a function for getting Details

```
public function getDetails()
{
    $st=$this->db->SELECT('cursadas.*, usuarios.name as usuarios, materias.name as materias_name')->from('cursadas')
        ->join('usuarios','usuarios.id=cursadas.user_id')
        ->join('materias','materias.id=cursadas.subject_id')
        ->WHERE('cursadas.user_id=',$this->session->userdata['id'])
        ->get()->result_array();
    return $st[0]; // or use the row function
}
```

And than in your view, use the corresponding indexes of $record

Comment: Mate, but whatwould be the indexes?
You mean this?
https://i.gyazo.com/0eb593492bec2b64074406db3ef23177.png

Comment: Yes, but dump the array first to see the correct spelling of indexes. Or you can printr

Comment: Pal,you are helping me a lot!,but can help me to figure it out about indexes..im out of practice and i dont get it :S.
What should i do in this case?

Comment: Look $record is the array you passed to the view. as per my query the indexes will be like $record[id], $record[usuarios], $record[materias_name] followed by grade and status if you want to get their labels as user and subject_id just change their names in the query after AS like "usuarios.name as user"